# Within a table do I need to have thead, tbody and tfooter?

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email

Guys I'm making an email for the first time in html, and I need to do this email in html, I don't want a ready solution please.

Within a table do I have to have thead, tbody and tfooter?

I believe that for the sake of semantics yes, but in an email need ??

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some useful links for better understanding how to create an email in html :) Please use the suggestions for a better experience :)

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

Comment: Please add a general overview of what info the links are meant to communicate. There's nothing worse coming over to a question after 4 years and finding an accepted answer that's full of dead links because the websites have changed or no longer exist.

Comment: You re absolutely right. I edited my answer :)

Comment: Helped a lot brother, vlw

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: **No, you don't.**

Some ESPs will insert these for you (when you post your code into a platform) but ultimately they aren't required for modern email clients.

I never include them. My structure is always as follows:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="class-name" style="width:###px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, it is important to note that including these tags isn't detrimental to your HTML.
So completely up to you if you decide to include them.

I would suggest checking out these links to get more up to speed on the industry standard for coding emails:

1. [Build an HTML Email Template From Scratch](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770) - Learn the basics of email template development from Nicole Merlin, a renowned expert in the email industry.
2. [Creating a Simple Responsive HTML Email](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978) - Also by Nicole Merlin however she now takes you through the more modern responsive email development techniques.

I would recommend taking the time to review these and follow along to really understand what is going on. There are other tutorials out there too, so you don't necessarily need to use the two above. They'll at least give you a starting point in what to search for.